# Permanently reversing a patch-file

Tags: linux, diff, patch

Sometimes, for whatever reason, I have to produce patch-files (under Linux) that are in the wrong direction.  I know that I can deal with this by using the `-R` switch when applying it via `patch`, but it would be nice if there were a way of permanently reversing the patch-file.  Is there a utility that can do this, or e.g. a regex that would be guaranteed to work?

**UPDATE**

Lie Ryan has [suggested a neat way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902388/permanently-reversing-a-patch-file/3902431#3902431).  However, it requires access to the original source file(s).  So I suppose I should update my question to state that I'm more after a way of achieving this given only the patch-file itself.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the tool `interdiff(1)` from [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/). In particular, the man page for `interdiff` says:

> To reverse a patch, use /dev/null for
>   diff2.

So,

```
$ interdiff -q file.patch /dev/null > reversed.patch
```

The `-q / --quiet` prevents the insertion of `reverted:` lines.

Comment: doesn't work. I've tried to apply the reversed patch to the file patched with the forward patch, and it fails. So this does not produce a correct reversed patch, at least not for all patches. I don't know whether interdiff is broken or this method is just wrong

Comment: I see, this *is* supposed to work according to interdiff's man page, so it's a bug in interdiff

Comment: @matteo `-q` was required for me. Edited.

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
patch -R file.txt file.patch
diff file.txt.orig file.txt > file.patch.rev
// you can then `rm file.txt.orig file.patch`
```

**EDIT:**

To reverse a unified diff, you need to change three things:

- the patch header
- the chunk header
- the + to - and - to +

So here's how a patch header for a looks like:

```
--- b.asm   2010-09-24 12:03:43.000000000 +1000    
+++ a.asm   2010-09-24 23:28:43.000000000 +1000
```

you need to reverse it so it looks like this:

```
--- a.asm   2010-09-24 23:28:43.000000000 +1000
+++ b.asm   2010-09-24 12:03:43.000000000 +1000
```

basically switch the order, and switch +++ to --- and vice versa.

Next, the chunk header:

```
@@ -29,5 +27,7 @@
```

You need to reverse the numbers, so it look like this:

```
@@ -27,7 +29,5 @@
```

basically, switch the number pairs

and last, switch every line beginning with + and every line beginning with -.

**EDIT:**

to switch the chunk header, you can do:

```
sed -e "s/@@ -\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\) +\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\) @@/@@ -\2 +\1 @@/"
```

to switch + to - and - to +, you can do:

```
sed -e "s/^+/P/" -e "s/^-/+/" -e "s/^P/-/"
```

**FINALLY:**

to reverse the patch header, do:

```
head -2 orig.diff | tac | sed -e "s/+++/PPP/" -e "s/---/+++/" -e "s/PPP/---/" > head
tail orig.diff -n+3 > tail
cat head tail > headtail
rm head tail
```

So, finally, our (quick and dirty) script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
F="$1"
head -2 $F | tac | sed -e "s/+++/PPP/" -e "s/---/+++/" -e "s/PPP/---/" > $F.head
tail $F -n+3 | sed -e "s/@@ -\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\) +\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\) @@/@@ -\2 +\1 @@/" -e "s/^+/P/" -e "s/^-/+/" -e "s/^P/-/" > $F.tail
cat $F.head $F.tail 
rm $F.head $F.tail
```

I tested it, and it seems to work.

though, to make things more maintainable, and cleaner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
swap() {
    sed -e "s/^$1/PPP/" -e "s/^$2/$1/" -e "s/^PPP/$2/"
}
file_header() {
    head -2 $1 | tac | swap +++ ---
}
fix_chunk_header() {
    sed -e "s/@@ -\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\) +\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\) @@/@@ -\2 +\1 @@/" 
}
fix_lines() {
    swap + -
}
file="$1"
file_header $file
tail $file -n+3 | fix_chunk_header | fix_lines
```

Comment: +1: I hadn't thought of this.  But out of interest, is there any way to do it without access to the original files?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: The file.txt.orig file are automatic backup generated by patch when you call it in the first line. I simply use that backup to regenerate the reversed patch.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: What I meant was, how could I do this if I *only* have the patch-file?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: hmm.. don't think there's a way to do that with `diff` and `patch`. I can probably concoct some sed script that substitute > with < and vice versa, if you give me some moment.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Don't put yourself out on my account!  I can probably do so myself, if I knew the specific things that need reversing (e.g. `+` and `-`).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: hmm... sorry about that, apparently it's not as trivial as I originally thought it'd be (i.e. not a one-liner sed). Anyway, there's three things you'd need to change. The patch header, chunk header, and the + to - (or > to <), I'll explain a bit above.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Thanks very much for all that.  I will give this a try tomorrow!

Comment: @LieRyan Thank you for posting this detailed account of reverse patching. I think this should be the correct answer since if we do not understand the tools then we cannot fully use them and that's why you get my +1.

Answer (score 6):

I had applied a patch `patch -N -p0 < path/file.patch` but i started facing compilation issues due to incomplete code all i did was to run this command `patch -p0 -R < path/file.patch` . Referred this [link](https://prajwalaa.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/remove-applied-patch-using-patch-command/)

Answer (score 2):

I reversed / restored original file with: `patch -Ri sample.patch`

Additional `-p0` or `-p1` options might be of help as well.